# Using S3 class to generate ggplot

Tags: r, class, ggplot2

I have been trying to learn how to use S3 class structures and I have ran into some difficulty trying to use ggplot within a plot function. I have some test data:

```
testdata = data.frame(col1 = rnorm(100), col2 = rnorm(100))
testdata = structure(list(testdata = testdata), class = "test")
```

Then I have my plot function:

```
plot.test = function (x, y, data)
{ 
  data = data$testdata
  ggplot(data = data, aes_string(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
}
```

So I want to be able to use this function just by using `plot()` instead of `plot.test()`. It works if I use `plot.test()` and give the function the x and y columns:

```
plot.test(x = 'col1', y = 'col2', data = testdata)
```

However when I just use `plot()`, I get an error:

```
plot(x = 'col1', y = 'col2', data = testdata)
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
5: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
6: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
7: In plot.window(...) : "data" is not a graphical parameter
```

I am obviously missing some knowledge of S3 classes somewhere...

Comment: I think I need `autoplot` and have therefore maybe answered my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out that if I change `plot.test` to `autoplot.test` then this works so long as I change the order of my variables:

```
testdata = data.frame(col1 = rnorm(100), col2 = rnorm(100))
testdata = structure(list(testdata = testdata), class = "test")
autoplot.test = function (x, y, data)
{ 
  data = data$testdata
  ggplot(data = data, aes_string(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
}
autoplot.test(testdata, x = 'col1', y = 'col2') ## works
autoplot(testdata, x = 'col1', y = 'col2') ## also works
```